# How to determine if a ARFaceAnchor is not updated in a ARSession

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, arkit, iphone-x

I have app where I used a `ARSession` with `ARFaceTrackingConfiguration`. I've save a copy of the anchor whenever it is updated in `session(_ session: ARSession, didUpdate anchors: [ARAnchor])`.

But when the face is no longer in the frame there is no way for the app to know. because this function won't be called.

I've tried writing a flag in `session(_ session: ARSession, didRemove anchors: [ARAnchor])` but that is not called because the anchor is not removed when face is no longer in from of the camera. I checked using the current frame of the session `frame.anchors.count`.

I found no other relevant function in `ARSessionDelegate` protocol. When the app was paused in the debugger I saw a private property of current frame called `detectedFaces` which was correctly set to 0 when you put the phone down. But since it's private I can't access it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`ARFaceAnchor` adopts the [`ARTrackable`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/artrackable) protocol, whose sole purpose is to tell you whether an anchor is being updated automatically by ARKit. The [`isTracked`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/artrackable/2928210-istracked) property is true if the anchor's transform has been updated in the current frame, and false otherwise.

Knowing *that* an anchor is no longer currently tracked is half the solution to your problem — the other thing you probably want to know is *when*. You have a couple of options there.

1. Keep references to the face anchors you've been using. When you get a delegate callback like `session(_ session: ARSession, didUpdate anchors: [ARAnchor])`, any anchors not in the list of those updated are likely stale, and you can check their `isTracked` property to verify.
2. Subscribe to the "first" callback for per-frame updates, `session(_ session: ARSession, didUpdate frame: ARFrame)`, or inspect the session's `currentFrame`, and iterate through the frame's `anchors` list to see which anchors conform to `ARTrackable` but report false for `isTracked`.